# Is there a way to dynamically change the output of credential.helper?

Tags: python, bash, git, github, sh

Is there a bash command that can dynamically change where Git's credential.helper stores credentials?

For example, if I were to say:

```
echo "url=https://USER:PASSWORD@github.com/OWNER/REPO.git" | git credential approve
```

If I wanted the credential to be stored in a file called "github", but wanted

```
echo "url=https://USER:PASSWORD@gitlab.com/OWNER/REPO.git" | git credential approve
```

To result in the credential being stored in a file called "gitlab"

Is there a way I can dynamically do this?
I know I can do `git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.{appropriateFile}'` before each one, but I don't actually want to change the server's .gitconfig really. It's not really mine to tweak with too much.

**Also**, as a bonus question, would there be a way to pipe the 2 commands together?
i.e.

```
echo git approve credential | -some way of changing the credential storage without editing .config-
```

Comment: To change a setting for a single Git command, use `git -c`: `git -c credential.helper 'store --file ...' credential approve` for instance. If you forget the `-c`, Git will use the most-local setting: the one from the `.git` for the repository, or the one from your `--global` setting, or the `--system` setting.